# UMP to Geometric distribution

Tags: inference, likelihood-ratio

Given the hypothesis

$$ H_0 : \theta_0 \ \ \ \text{vs} \ \ \ H_1 : \theta_1 $$

I want to find the Uniformly Most Powerful test (UMP).

Well, we know by the Neyman–Pearson lemma that:
$$  \frac{f(\widetilde{x}/\theta_1)}{f(\widetilde{x}/\theta_0)}  > k $$ to some $$ k > 0 $$ we will have a UMP with size $$ \alpha $$ such that $$ P(X \space \epsilon \space R \mid \theta = \theta_0) = \alpha  $$

Doing this to the Geometric distribution, I will find something like this:

$$ \sum{X_i} \geq \frac{k + n \ln\left( \frac{\theta_1}{\theta_0} \right)}{\ln \left( \frac{1 - \theta_1}{1 - \theta_0} \right)} $$

My doubt is how to proceed from here. I know that $$ \frac{k + n \ln\left(\frac{\theta_1}{\theta_0}\right)}{\ln\left(\frac{1 - \theta_1}{1 - \theta_0}\right)}  = c $$ such that

$$ P\left( \sum{X_i} \geq c \right) = \alpha $$ but how can I sum all the geometric distribution? Is this new distribution a normal or another one?

Comment: your critical region is wrong, the correct should be: $P(\sum X_{i} \leq c)$ if $\theta_{0}<\theta_{1}$